# Retrieving private key from CSR

Tags: security-certificate

I generated CSR before obtaining a certificate from a CA Authority using the following [documentation](https://www.digicert.com/util/csr-creation-microsoft-servers-using-digicert-utility.htm). I am wondering how can I retrieve private key from the generated CSR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't; it doesn't work like that. A CSR is derived from the private key, not the other way around. If that were possible, then Certificate Authority would be able to derive your private key from the CSR you give them, and ideally your private key should never leave your server.

Check with DigiCert to confirm, but the tool probably automatically saves the private into Windows' Certificate Manager. Open **certmgr.msc** and search for the private key there.

Comment: or maybe because he/she hasn't clicked > Account and provided the username and password `The DigiCert Utility lets you log into your account and view your orders. Once logged in, you can generate and upload a CSV or install certificates that have been completed validation.` DigiCert doesn't provide a key via their tool... the installer does that for you... and its a paid service just like any other good SSL provider: https://www.digicert.com/util/ssl-certificate-installation-using-digicert-utility-for-microsoft-servers.htm

Comment: @Andrew Lott In which folder I should search for private key?

Comment: @SimonHayter I am just using their tool to generate CSR and planning to use GlobelCert for getting domain validated certificate.

Comment: Try not using their tool and using a tutorial provided by who is actually providing you with the SSL. i.e GoDaddy > https://uk.godaddy.com/help/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-microsoft-iis-8-4950 digicert > https://www.digicert.com/util/ssl-certificate-installation-using-digicert-utility-for-microsoft-servers.htm etc

Answer (score 1):

Since the documentation link provided is for Windows, one doesn't have access to the private key until after the certificate request has been completed. This is the last step mentioned in your documentation ([SSL Certificate Importing Instructions: DigiCert Certificate Utility](https://www.digicert.com/util/ssl-certificate-installation-using-digicert-utility-for-microsoft-servers.htm)).

With the certificate properly installed you may be able to export the certificate (certmgr.msc), typically as a .pfx, which would include the private key. There are also instructions in your documentation for doing this here: [DigiCert Certificate Utility SSL Certificate Export Instructions (PFX Format)](https://www.digicert.com/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm)